# PHPMailer using gmail with XOAUTH2: How to auto get a new refresh token when the current refresh token is expired?

Tags: php, oauth, gmail, phpmailer

I follow [*Using Gmail with XOAUTH2* (PHPMailer Wiki)](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) and [*How to Send Emails Using PHPMailer with Gmail XOAUTH2?* (Chandan for w3jar.com; May 2019)](https://www.w3jar.com/php-send-emails-using-phpmailer/).

Today, my website can't send an email because the refresh token was expired.

Then I read the PHPMailer Wiki again and found this:

> [image]

So, I need to go to this page and click `Google`.

> [image]

Then choose my account that will send an email.

> [image]

The new token refresh will show like this.

> [image]

After that, I need to copy this refresh token and past this in my send-email function.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;

function sendEmail($email, $title, $detail)
{
    try {
        $refreshToken = 'I am here';   //////// I am hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        //Server settings
        $mail->*ANY*;

        //Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
        $provider = new Google([
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret
        ]);

        //Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
        $mail->setOAuth(new OAuth([
            'provider' => $provider,
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
            'userName' => $senderEmail,
        ]));

        if ($mail->send())  return true;


        return false;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That is what I have to do when the token expired.

Gmail doesn't have any notice for a refresh token expired.

It's causing problems for people using my site. Until someone contacted me to tell me about this problem.

How to auto get refresh token?

This step needs someone to click on the `Google` button and then click Gmail account to get a refresh token.

Is it possible with PHP? How can I automate the procedure?

Comment: Whenever you get a new access token, you may also receive a new refresh token. When you do, you should replace your existing refresh token with it. That way the authentication will keep rolling indefinitely. This is entirely down to the configuration of the OAuth client though, not something that PHPMailer is responsible for.

Comment: I am new to token. 
Is an access token mean a token that has no expiration date? 
Did you mean replacing the access token instead of the refresh token?
Or do you mean the second refresh token has no expiration date?

Comment: No. When you perform OAuth authentication (using the id and secret), it will give you an access token (much like a cookie) and a refresh token. The access token usually has a short expiry time (e.g. 1 day), refresh usually much longer, and when it expires, you use the refresh token to get another access token. When you do that it can also give you a new refresh token, which you should save and use in future requests. The OAuth client should take care of this for you.

Comment: Thank @Synchro,
I think the image below `The new token refresh will show like this.` is the refresh token because it can be used for more than 1 day. So, as you said `which you should save and use in future requests.` How to do that?
I am using the refresh token in the send-email function and the result from $mail->send() is true or false.
I don't know where I can get a new refresh token.

Comment: That’s the part that is specific to the OAuth client library, so I suggest reading their docs as it is separate from PHPMailer.

Comment: This will fail as setOAuth expects a OAuthTokenProvider and not an OAuth object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am using 2 step verification.
ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mte7LroYd74&list=LL&index=1&t=2s